# Does TypeScript (^2.3.3) lose type information on array spread?

Tags: arrays, typescript

When I create a new array by using the array spread operator **TypeScript seems to lose the correct type information**.

This does not happen if I create the new array with `Array.combine()`.

I've prepared a simple example to demonstrate this. I use declaration merging to have the constants (`ACES`, `TWOS`, etc.) have their corresponding type. Then I create the type `Category` to be a "supertype".

The variable `sectionsSpread` is of type `string[]` after creating it with the array spread operator. The variable `sectionsCombined` is of type `Category[]`.

I expected the variable `sectionsSpread` to be also of type `Category[]`.

Is this a bug? Have I got array spreading wrong?

```
const ACES = 'ACES';
type ACES = typeof ACES;

const TWOS = 'TWOS';
type TWOS = typeof TWOS;

const THREES = 'THREES';
type THREES = typeof THREES;

const FULL_HOUSE = 'FULL_HOUSE';
type FULL_HOUSE = typeof FULL_HOUSE;

const SMALL_STRAIGHT = 'SMALL_STRAIGHT';
type SMALL_STRAIGHT = typeof SMALL_STRAIGHT;

const LARGE_STRAIGHT = 'LARGE_STRAIGHT';
type LARGE_STRAIGHT = typeof LARGE_STRAIGHT;

type Category = ACES | TWOS | THREES |
    FULL_HOUSE | SMALL_STRAIGHT | LARGE_STRAIGHT;

const upperSection: Array<Category> = [ACES, TWOS, THREES];
const lowerSection: Array<Category> = [FULL_HOUSE, SMALL_STRAIGHT, LARGE_STRAIGHT]; 

const sectionsSpread = [
    ...upperSection,
    ...lowerSection
];

const sectionsCombined = upperSection.concat(lowerSection);
```

**UDATE**

@dbandstra and @basarat pointed me in the right direction. After reading the [suggested blog post](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/04/typescript-2-1-literal-type-widening) I think I understand **Literal Type Widening**. But this still doesn't explain the behaviour of the `typeof` operator in this context for me.

I hope the following examples make my problem more clear:

```
const ACES = 'ACES';
type ACES = 'ACES'; // non-widening literal type 

const TWOS = 'TWOS';
type TWOS = 'TWOS'; // non-widening literal type

type Category = ACES | TWOS; // are these values or types?

const upperSection: Category[] = [ACES]; 
const lowerSection: Category[] = [TWOS];

const sectionsSpread = [
    ...upperSection,
    ...lowerSection,
]; // is of type Category[]
```

If I use `typeof` the variable `sectionsSpread` ends up being of type `string[]` instead:

```
const ACES = 'ACES';
type ACES = typeof ACES; // what does typeof do here?

const TWOS = 'TWOS';
type TWOS = typeof TWOS; // what does typeof do here?

type Category = ACES | TWOS; // are these values or types?

const upperSection: Category[] = [ACES]; 
const lowerSection: Category[] = [TWOS];

const sectionsSpread = [
    ...upperSection,
    ...lowerSection,
]; // is of type string[]
```

Comment: Behaviour is discussed here (widening vs. non-widening literals): https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2017/02/04/typescript-2-1-literal-type-widening You could fix your array literal by defining e.g. `const ACES = 'ACES' as 'ACES';` or something to that effect, to make the original consts 'non-widening'.

Comment: Is the title supposed to be loose or lose?

Comment: @Zze You're right. That's a type. Obviously it should have been _lose_.

Comment: And another typo: In the introducing text I meant `Array.concat()` and **not** `Array.combine()`.

Answer (score 2):

This is widening vs. non-widening. An explicit annotation means TypeScript doesn't change its meaning when assigning to other values.

## Widening:

```
const ACES = 'ACES';
type Category = typeof ACES;

const upperSection: Category[] = []; 

const sectionsSpread = [
    ...upperSection,
]; // string[]
```

## Non widening:

```
const ACES = 'ACES';
type Category = 'ACES';

const upperSection: Category[] = []; 

const sectionsSpread = [
    ...upperSection,
]; // Category
```